# Chai unittesting - expect(42).to.be.an('integer')

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

According to http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#a, `a`/`an` can be used to check for the type of a variable.

> .a(type)
>
> `@param{ String } type`
>
> `@param{ String } message _optional_`
>
> The `a` and `an` assertions are aliases that can be used
>   either as language chains or to assert a value's type.

However, I'm not able to check for the variable beeing an integer. The given examples, e.g. `expect('1337').to.be.a('string');` work for me, but the following does not:

```
expect(42).to.be.an('integer');
expect(42).to.be.an('Integer');
expect(42).to.be.an('int');
expect(42).to.be.an('Int');
```

All of them are giving me the following error when running mocha:

```
Uncaught AssertionError: expected 42 to be an integer
```

How do I test with chai for a variable beeing an integer?

Comment: I tried the docs and didn't find any comment in them about types, so I'll take an educated guess.  Try typeof `Number` since Javascript doesn't have an integer type.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher: On the left side you need to click on "a / an". But you were right, I can check for "number". May you write that as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have a separate `integer` type.

Everything is a [IEE 754 floating point number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), which would of type `number`.

Comment: Probably because while you technically answered the question "How do I test with chai for a variable beeing an integer?", the spirit of the question is more like "How do I test with chai for a variable being a number which has a modulus 1 equal to 0?

But then again, your answer was accepted, so maybe the downvote is unwarranted.

Comment: Can't edit my previous comment anymore, but a better rewording would be "How do I test with chai for a variable being a whole number?".

Edit: The unfortunate thing is though that the definition of "whole number" in the dictionary says "a number without fractions; an integer."

Answer (score 53):

A bit late, but for people coming from search engines, here is another solution:

```js
var expect = require('chai').expect

expect(foo).to.be.a('number')
expect(foo % 1).to.equal(0)
```

The number check is required because of things such as `true % 1 === 0` or `null % 1 === 0`.

Comment: What's the difference if we don't use `be`. This works for me `expect(foo % 1).to.equal(0)` ?

Comment: As per [the doc](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/), to/be/is/etc are only here to provide readability. This is confirmed by [the code](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/blob/0064f2604959260cf91282083cdcb7ba8acfce30/lib/chai/core/assertions.js#L43-L48). I'll edit as `expect(foo % 1).to.equal(0)` is more straight forward than `expect(foo % 1).to.be.equal(0)`.

Comment: If foo is 1.0 this assertion will return true. This may not matter for many use cases, but it's worth pointing out

Comment: @Reagankm: sadly, JavaScript only has two numeric types: Number or BigInt. Number is a 64-bit floating point number. There is no integer support. See the [ECMAScript 262 spec about the Number type](https://262.ecma-international.org/14.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-number-type).

Answer (score 16):

This is also possible (at least whithin node):

```
expect(42).to.satisfy(Number.isInteger);
```

Here is a more advanced example:

```
expect({NUM: 1}).to.have.property('NUM').which.is.a('number').above(0).and.satisfy(Number.isInteger);
```

Answer (score 5):

I feel your pain, this is what I came up with:

```
var assert = require('chai').assert;

describe('Something', function() {

    it('should be an integer', function() {

        var result = iShouldReturnInt();

        assert.isNumber(result);

        var isInt = result % 1 === 0;
        assert(isInt, 'not an integer:' + result);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the browser/context you are running in there is also a function hanging off of Number that would be of some use.

```
var value = 42;
Number.isInteger(value).should.be.true;
```

It has not been adopted everywhere, but most of the places that matter (Chrome, FFox, Opera, Node)

[More Info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger)

Answer (score 0):

Another [not optimal] solution (why not?!)

```
const actual = String(val).match(/^\d+$/);
expect(actual).to.be.an('array');
expect(actual).to.have.lengthOf(1);
```