# How to check if value is a positive number using Chai?

Tags: javascript, chai

I'm trying to figure out how to check if a value is a positive number (bigger than zero) by using Chai. What I tried:

```
expect(5).that.is.a('number');
```

But it also works for `-5` and `0`. I also tried to change to `integer` but js does not have this type. How can I check it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `above(val)` to check if a number is above a value.

This will make sure that the value is both a number and that it's above whatever value you want. In this case, since you want it to be a positive value, we'll use `above(0)`.

If you want to also check if it's a whole number, you can use `expect(val % 1).to.equal(0)` as shown in [Chai Unittesting - expect(42).to.be.an('integer')](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35791091/13175138)

```js
chai.expect(5).to.be.above(0)

try {
  chai.expect(-5).to.be.above(0)
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error.message);
}
try {
  chai.expect(0).to.be.above(0)
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error.message);
}

try {
  chai.expect('5').to.be.above(0)
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error.message);
}

try {
  let val = 2.5;
  chai.expect(val).to.be.above(0);
  chai.expect(val % 1,'to be a whole number').to.equal(0)
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error.message);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chai/4.2.0/chai.min.js"></script>
```